# java - Eclipse gives me an error when i create a new project

Tags: java, eclipse, class, methods, compilation

I am using Eclipse IDE Galileo, on windows 8.1

When I want to create a new project, I go to file> new> java project.

I name my project then click on finish.

I then open the src file under my project and right click it. new> class. And I name my class
But before i even write any program, I have these errors. So can anybody please help me? Thanks in advance.

Here's the errors:  [image: http://tinypic.com?ref=b65yk7img/]

**NOTE:** My friend have the same problem, but she is using windows xp.

Comment: There is nothing in that link.

Comment: please explain your problem clearly,`what is the error message??` and i think you dont have jre path set in eclipse

Answer (score 2):

Dear @rebecca richa This problem will occur if your project have not JDK libraries. To add JDK libraries follow the following steps

right click on project --> Properties --> java build path --> select Libraries tab --> now click on Add Library --> select JRE System Library --> select Workspace Default JRE

your problem will be solved. other wise click on alternate JRE and select the path of jdk in your system where you[image] have installed. now your problem will definitely solved.

for further help follow the image below

Answer (score 1):

Seems like eclipse couldn't find Java Classes for your project.

Do This...

1. Right Click your project
2. Hover on Build Path
3. Select Configure Build Path...
4. Select Libraries Tab in the newly opened window
5. Click Add Library
6. Select JRE System Library from the newly opened popup
7. Close the Window using OK

This should remove the errors

Comment: Note: OP selected a JRE system library (namely `OGSI/Minimum...`). This one is very limited. Use `JavaSE-1.7` (or a lower version if you don't have Java 7 installed).